# andorid emulator displays black screen after build aosp

Tags: android-emulator, android-source

I met a problem when I launched the android emulator after build aosp successfully, emulator showed a black screen. Have you met this problem before?

this is my environment

> ```
> CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 4800H
> MEM: 32GB DDR 3200 MHZ
> Build in:  VMWare with AMD-V enabled (Windows 10 without Hyper-v): Ubuntu 20.04 
> Branch: android-11.0.0_r17
> Target: aosp_cf_x86_phone-userdebug
>
> PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
> PLATFORM_VERSION=11
> TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_cf_x86_phone
> TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
> TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
> TARGET_ARCH=x86
> TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=x86
> HOST_ARCH=x86_64
> HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
> HOST_OS=linux
> HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-5.4.0-56-generic-x86_64-Ubuntu-20.04.1-LTS
> HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
> HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
> HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
> HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
> BUILD_ID=RP1A.201105.002
> OUT_DIR=out
> PRODUCT_SOONG_NAMESPACES=device/generic/goldfish-opengl hardware/google/camera hardware/google/camera/devices/EmulatedCamera  external/mesa3d
> ```

This is emulator logs:

> dvdface@ubuntu:~/Source/aosp$ emulator -verbose emulator: Android
> emulator version 30.0.21.0 (build_id 6647651) (CL:N/A) emulator: Found
> ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT:
> /home/dvdface/Source/aosp/out/target/product/vsoc_x86 emulator: Found
> build target architecture: x86 emulator: argv[0]: 'emulator'; program
> directory:
> '/home/dvdface/Source/aosp/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64'
> emulator: emuDirName:
> '/home/dvdface/Source/aosp/prebuilts/android-emulator/emulator'
> emulator: Probing for
> /home/dvdface/Source/aosp/out/target/product/vsoc_x86/kernel-ranchu-64:
> file missing emulator: try dir
> /home/dvdface/Source/aosp/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64
> emulator: Trying emulator path
> '/home/dvdface/Source/aosp/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386'
> emulator: Found target-specific 64-bit emulator binary:
> /home/dvdface/Source/aosp/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386
> emulator: Adding library search path:
> '/home/dvdface/Source/aosp/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64'
> emulator: Adding library search path:
> '/home/dvdface/Source/aosp/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/gles_angle'
> emulator: Adding library search path:
> '/home/dvdface/Source/aosp/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/gles_angle9'
> emulator: Adding library search path:
> '/home/dvdface/Source/aosp/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/gles_angle11'
> emulator: Adding library search path:
> '/home/dvdface/Source/aosp/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/gles_swiftshader'
> emulator: Adding library search path:
> '/home/dvdface/Source/aosp/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/libstdc++'
> emulator: Adding library search path for Qt:
> '/home/dvdface/Source/aosp/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/qt/lib'
> emulator: Silencing all qWarning(); use qCWarning(...) instead:
> QT_LOGGING_RULES=default.warning=false emulator: Setting Qt plugin
> search path:
> QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=/home/dvdface/Source/aosp/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/qt/plugins
> emulator: Setting Qt to use software OpenGL: QT_OPENGL=software
> emulator: Setting QML to use software QtQuick2D:
> QMLSCENE_DEVICE=softwarecontext emulator: Overriding pre-existing bad
> Qt high dpi settings... emulator: Setting LD_PRELOAD to
> /home/dvdface/Source/aosp/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/qt/lib/libfreetype.so.6
> emulator: Running
> :/home/dvdface/Source/aosp/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386
> emulator: qemu backend: argv[00] =
> "/home/dvdface/Source/aosp/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386"
> emulator: qemu backend: argv[01] = "-verbose" emulator: Concatenated
> backend parameters:
> /home/dvdface/Source/aosp/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386
> -verbose emulator: found Android build root: /home/dvdface/Source/aosp emulator: found Android build out:
> /home/dvdface/Source/aosp/out/target/product/vsoc_x86 emulator: Cannot
> find boot properties file:
> /home/dvdface/Source/aosp/out/target/product/vsoc_x86/boot.prop
>
> emulator: Found target API sdkVersion: 30
>
> emulator: Invalid int property:
> 'ro.build.version.incremental:eng.dvdfac.20201204.223437' emulator:
> autoconfig: -skin HVGA emulator: autoconfig: -skindir
> /home/dvdface/Source/aosp/development/tools/emulator/skins/ emulator:
> autoconfig: -kernel
> /home/dvdface/Source/aosp/prebuilts/qemu-kernel/x86/ranchu/kernel-qemu
> emulator: Target arch = 'x86' emulator: Auto-config: -qemu -cpu qemu32
> emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel image requires new device naming scheme.
> emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel does not support YAFFS2 partitions.
> emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk
> /home/dvdface/Source/aosp/out/target/product/vsoc_x86/ramdisk.img
> emulator: autoconfig: -sysdir
> /home/dvdface/Source/aosp/out/target/product/vsoc_x86 emulator: Using
> initial system image:
> /home/dvdface/Source/aosp/out/target/product/vsoc_x86/system.img
> emulator: Using initial vendor image:
> /home/dvdface/Source/aosp/out/target/product/vsoc_x86/vendor.img
> emulator: autoconfig: -data
> /home/dvdface/Source/aosp/out/target/product/vsoc_x86/userdata-qemu.img
> emulator: autoconfig: -initdata
> /home/dvdface/Source/aosp/out/target/product/vsoc_x86/userdata.img
> emulator: autoconfig: -cache
> /home/dvdface/Source/aosp/out/target/product/vsoc_x86/cache.img
> emulator: Increasing RAM size to 2048MB emulator: VM heap size 48MB is
> below hardware specified minimum of 512MB,setting it to that value
> emulator: System image is read only emulator: Found 1 DNS servers:
> 127.0.0.53 emulator: trying to load skin file '/home/dvdface/Source/aosp/development/tools/emulator/skins//HVGA/layout'
> emulator: WARNING: encryption is off emulator: CPU Acceleration:
> working emulator: CPU Acceleration status: KVM (version 12) is
> installed and usable. emulator: GPU emulation enabled using 'host'
> mode emulator: Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
> emulator: VERBOSE: MultiDisplay.cpp:304: create display 0 emulator:
> VERBOSE: MultiDisplay.cpp:394: setDisplayPose 0 x 0 y 0 w 320 h 480
> dpi 0 emulator: VERBOSE: load_config.cpp:242: Verified boot params
> were not found. emulator: Found 1 DNS servers: 127.0.0.53 Content of
> hardware configuration file:   hw.cpu.arch = x86   hw.cpu.model =
> qemu32   hw.cpu.ncore = 2   hw.ramSize = 2048   hw.screen =
> multi-touch   hw.mainKeys = true   hw.trackBall = true   hw.keyboard =
> false   hw.keyboard.lid = false   hw.keyboard.charmap = qwerty2
> hw.dPad = true   hw.rotaryInput = false   hw.gsmModem = true   hw.gps
> = true   hw.battery = true   hw.accelerometer = true   hw.gyroscope = true   hw.audioInput = true   hw.audioOutput = true   hw.sdCard = true
> disk.cachePartition = true   disk.cachePartition.path =
> /home/dvdface/Source/aosp/out/target/product/vsoc_x86/cache.img
> disk.cachePartition.size = 66m   test.quitAfterBootTimeOut = -1
> test.delayAdbTillBootComplete = 0   test.monitorAdb = 0   hw.lcd.width
> = 320   hw.lcd.height = 480   hw.lcd.depth = 16   hw.lcd.density = 160   hw.lcd.backlight = true   hw.lcd.vsync = 60   hw.gltransport = pipe
> hw.gltransport.asg.writeBufferSize = 1048576
> hw.gltransport.asg.writeStepSize = 4096
> hw.gltransport.asg.dataRingSize = 32768
> hw.gltransport.drawFlushInterval = 800   hw.displayRegion.0.1.xOffset
> = -1   hw.displayRegion.0.1.yOffset = -1   hw.displayRegion.0.1.width = 0   hw.displayRegion.0.1.height = 0   hw.display1.width = 0   hw.display1.height = 0   hw.display1.density = 0   hw.display1.xOffset
> = -1   hw.display1.yOffset = -1   hw.display1.flag = 0   hw.display2.width = 0   hw.display2.height = 0   hw.display2.density =
> 0   hw.display2.xOffset = -1   hw.display2.yOffset = -1
> hw.display2.flag = 0   hw.display3.width = 0   hw.display3.height = 0
> hw.display3.density = 0   hw.display3.xOffset = -1
> hw.display3.yOffset = -1   hw.display3.flag = 0   hw.gpu.enabled =
> true   hw.gpu.mode = host   hw.initialOrientation = portrait
> hw.camera.back = emulated   hw.camera.front = none   vm.heapSize = 512
> hw.sensors.light = true   hw.sensors.pressure = true
> hw.sensors.humidity = true   hw.sensors.proximity = true
> hw.sensors.magnetic_field = true
> hw.sensors.magnetic_field_uncalibrated = true
> hw.sensors.gyroscope_uncalibrated = true   hw.sensors.orientation =
> true   hw.sensors.temperature = true   hw.sensor.hinge = false
> hw.sensor.hinge.count = 0   hw.sensor.hinge.type = 0   hw.useext4 =
> true   hw.arc = false   hw.arc.autologin = false   kernel.path =
> /home/dvdface/Source/aosp/prebuilts/qemu-kernel/x86/ranchu/kernel-qemu
> kernel.newDeviceNaming = yes   kernel.supportsYaffs2 = no
> disk.ramdisk.path =
> /home/dvdface/Source/aosp/out/target/product/vsoc_x86/ramdisk.img
> disk.systemPartition.initPath =
> /home/dvdface/Source/aosp/out/target/product/vsoc_x86/system.img
> disk.systemPartition.size = 800m   disk.vendorPartition.initPath =
> /home/dvdface/Source/aosp/out/target/product/vsoc_x86/vendor.img
> disk.vendorPartition.size = 800m   disk.dataPartition.path =
> /home/dvdface/Source/aosp/out/target/product/vsoc_x86/userdata-qemu.img
> disk.dataPartition.size = 800m   PlayStore.enabled = false   avd.name
> =    avd.id =    fastboot.forceColdBoot = false   android.avd.home = /home/dvdface/.android/avd . QEMU options list:
> emulator: argv[00] =
> "/home/dvdface/Source/aosp/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386"
> emulator: argv[01] = "-dns-server" emulator: argv[02] = "127.0.0.53"
> emulator: argv[03] = "-serial" emulator: argv[04] = "null" emulator:
> argv[05] = "-device" emulator: argv[06] =
> "goldfish_pstore,addr=0xff018000,size=0x10000,file=/home/dvdface/Source/aosp/out/target/product/vsoc_x86/build.avd/data/misc/pstore/pstore.bin"
> emulator: argv[07] = "-cpu" emulator: argv[08] = "android32" emulator:
> argv[09] = "-enable-kvm" emulator: argv[10] = "-smp" emulator:
> argv[11] = "cores=2" emulator: argv[12] = "-m" emulator: argv[13] =
> "2048" emulator: argv[14] = "-lcd-density" emulator: argv[15] = "160"
> emulator: argv[16] = "-object" emulator: argv[17] =
> "iothread,id=disk-iothread" emulator: argv[18] = "-nodefaults"
> emulator: argv[19] = "-kernel" emulator: argv[20] =
> "/home/dvdface/Source/aosp/prebuilts/qemu-kernel/x86/ranchu/kernel-qemu"
> emulator: argv[21] = "-initrd" emulator: argv[22] =
> "/home/dvdface/Source/aosp/out/target/product/vsoc_x86/ramdisk.img"
> emulator: argv[23] = "-drive" emulator: argv[24] =
> "if=none,index=0,id=system,if=none,file=/home/dvdface/Source/aosp/out/target/product/vsoc_x86/system.img,read-only"
> emulator: argv[25] = "-device" emulator: argv[26] =
> "virtio-blk-pci,drive=system,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify"
> emulator: argv[27] = "-drive" emulator: argv[28] =
> "if=none,index=1,id=cache,if=none,file=/home/dvdface/Source/aosp/out/target/product/vsoc_x86/cache.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576"
> emulator: argv[29] = "-device" emulator: argv[30] =
> "virtio-blk-pci,drive=cache,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify"
> emulator: argv[31] = "-drive" emulator: argv[32] =
> "if=none,index=2,id=userdata,if=none,file=/home/dvdface/Source/aosp/out/target/product/vsoc_x86/userdata-qemu.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576" emulator: argv[33] = "-device" emulator: argv[34] =
> "virtio-blk-pci,drive=userdata,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify"
> emulator: argv[35] = "-drive" emulator: argv[36] =
> "if=none,index=3,id=vendor,if=none,file=/home/dvdface/Source/aosp/out/target/product/vsoc_x86/vendor.img,read-only"
> emulator: argv[37] = "-device" emulator: argv[38] =
> "virtio-blk-pci,drive=vendor,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify"
> emulator: argv[39] = "-netdev" emulator: argv[40] = "user,id=mynet"
> emulator: argv[41] = "-device" emulator: argv[42] =
> "virtio-net-pci,netdev=mynet" emulator: argv[43] = "-device" emulator:
> argv[44] = "virtio-rng-pci" emulator: argv[45] = "-show-cursor"
> emulator: argv[46] = "-L" emulator: argv[47] =
> "/home/dvdface/Source/aosp/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib/pc-bios"
> emulator: argv[48] = "-soundhw" emulator: argv[49] = "hda" emulator:
> argv[50] = "-vga" emulator: argv[51] = "none" emulator: argv[52] =
> "-append" emulator: argv[53] = "qemu=1 no_timer_check
> androidboot.hardware=ranchu androidboot.serialno=EMULATOR30X0X21X0
> clocksource=pit no-kvmclock android.qemud=1 console=0
> android.checkjni=1 qemu.gles=1
> qemu.settings.system.screen_off_timeout=2147483647 qemu.vsync=60
> qemu.gltransport=pipe qemu.gltransport.drawFlushInterval=800
> qemu.opengles.version=131072 cma=4M@0-4G
> androidboot.android_dt_dir=/sys/bus/platform/devices/ANDR0001:00/properties/android/
> loop.max_part=7 ramoops.mem_address=0xff018000
> ramoops.mem_size=0x10000 memmap=0x10000$0xff018000
> qemu.dalvik.vm.heapsize=512m qemu.camera_protocol_ver=1" emulator:
> argv[54] = "-android-hw" emulator: argv[55] =
> "/home/dvdface/Source/aosp/out/target/product/vsoc_x86/hardware-qemu.ini"
> Concatenated QEMU options:
> /home/dvdface/Source/aosp/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386
> -dns-server 127.0.0.53 -serial null -device goldfish_pstore,addr=0xff018000,size=0x10000,file=/home/dvdface/Source/aosp/out/target/product/vsoc_x86/build.avd/data/misc/pstore/pstore.bin
> -cpu android32 -enable-kvm -smp cores=2 -m 2048 -lcd-density 160 -object iothread,id=disk-iothread -nodefaults -kernel /home/dvdface/Source/aosp/prebuilts/qemu-kernel/x86/ranchu/kernel-qemu
> -initrd /home/dvdface/Source/aosp/out/target/product/vsoc_x86/ramdisk.img
> -drive if=none,index=0,id=system,if=none,file=/home/dvdface/Source/aosp/out/target/product/vsoc_x86/system.img,read-only
> -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=system,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify
> -drive if=none,index=1,id=cache,if=none,file=/home/dvdface/Source/aosp/out/target/product/vsoc_x86/cache.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576
> -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=cache,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify
> -drive if=none,index=2,id=userdata,if=none,file=/home/dvdface/Source/aosp/out/target/product/vsoc_x86/userdata-qemu.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576
> -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=userdata,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify
> -drive if=none,index=3,id=vendor,if=none,file=/home/dvdface/Source/aosp/out/target/product/vsoc_x86/vendor.img,read-only
> -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=vendor,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify
> -netdev user,id=mynet -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=mynet -device virtio-rng-pci -show-cursor -L
> /home/dvdface/Source/aosp/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib/pc-bios
> -soundhw hda -vga none -append 'qemu=1 no_timer_check androidboot.hardware=ranchu androidboot.serialno=EMULATOR30X0X21X0
> clocksource=pit no-kvmclock android.qemud=1 console=0
> android.checkjni=1 qemu.gles=1
> qemu.settings.system.screen_off_timeout=2147483647 qemu.vsync=60
> qemu.gltransport=pipe qemu.gltransport.drawFlushInterval=800
> qemu.opengles.version=131072 cma=4M@0-4G
> androidboot.android_dt_dir=/sys/bus/platform/devices/ANDR0001:00/properties/android/
> loop.max_part=7 ramoops.mem_address=0xff018000
> ramoops.mem_size=0x10000 memmap=0x10000$0xff018000
> qemu.dalvik.vm.heapsize=512m qemu.camera_protocol_ver=1' -android-hw
> /home/dvdface/Source/aosp/out/target/product/vsoc_x86/hardware-qemu.ini
> emulator: Android qemu version 30.0.21.0 (build_id 6647651) (CL:N/A)
>
> emulator: Starting QEMU main loop emulator: registered
> 'boot-properties' qemud service emulator: Adding boot property:
> 'ro.opengles.version' = '131072' emulator: Adding boot property:
> 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'back' emulator: Adding boot property:
> 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '512m' emulator: Adding boot property:
> 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '1' emulator: Adding boot property:
> 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '160' emulator: goldfish_events.have-dpad:
> true emulator: goldfish_events.have-trackball: true emulator:
> goldfish_events.have-camera: true emulator:
> goldfish_events.have-keyboard: false emulator:
> goldfish_events.have-lidswitch: false emulator:
> goldfish_events.have-tabletmode: false emulator:
> goldfish_events.have-touch: false emulator:
> goldfish_events.have-multitouch: true emulator: control console
> listening on port 5554, ADB on port 5555 Not using any http proxy
> emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.timezone' =
> 'America/Los_Angeles' emulator: android_hw_fingerprint_init:
> fingerprint qemud listen service initialized
>
> emulator: VERBOSE: GrpcServices.cpp:279: Started GRPC server at
> 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local emulator: emulator_window_fb_rotate
>
> emulator: VERBOSE: AdbInterface.cpp:355:  no root specified:
> emulator: VERBOSE: AdbInterface.cpp:355:  no root specified:
> emulator: VERBOSE: AdbInterface.cpp:385: Found: 1 adb executables
> emulator: VERBOSE: AdbInterface.cpp:387: Adb:
> /home/dvdface/Source/aosp/out/soong/host/linux-x86/bin/adb emulator:
> No acpi ini file provided, using default
>
> emulator: VERBOSE: AdbInterface.cpp:408:
> Path:/home/dvdface/Source/aosp/out/soong/host/linux-x86/bin/adb
> protocol version: 41 emulator: Adding boot property:
> 'ro.opengles.version' = '131072' emulator: Adding boot property:
> 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'back' emulator: Adding boot property:
> 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '512m' emulator: Adding boot property:
> 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '1' emulator: Adding boot property:
> 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '160' emulator: Adding boot property:
> 'qemu.timezone' = 'America/Los_Angeles' emulator: No acpi ini file
> provided, using default
>
> emulator: No acpi ini file provided, using default
>
> emulator: No acpi ini file provided, using default
>
> emulator: No acpi ini file provided, using default

Comment: I am facing the same exact issue, I've trying for hours now with no luck. I hope someone can give us some light. Did you mange to solve it?